# Does it cause problems if I don't set empty variables according to their data type but to null?

Tags: javascript

With placeholder variables which are to be filled later with data from a database you can obviously do it in both ways. The only question is, are there any circumstances in which JavaScript treats **null** differently than an array with no elements or an object with no properties?

Does JavaScript ever treat:

```
let userdetails = null
```

differently from either:

```
let userdetails = {}
//or
let userdetails = []
```

Comment: If you try to use properties or array indexes without initializing it to the correct type, you'll get errors.

Comment: If you're not going to use the variable until you fill it in, you don't need to give it an initial value at all.

Comment: beside what @Barmar said it would be also good to initialize the data type you want it would be good in high scale systems because you don't need to back every time to the variables to check what they are used for.

Comment: If there is a chance your returned data will be empty, and you need a way to differentiate between "not loaded" and "loaded but empty", then `null` is a better option.

Comment: The best practice is to set the variable to what is expected to be.
these are some reasons:

 1. Logic
 2. To be not confusing to any developer that comes after you
 3. You will get an Error if you want to use the properties of specfic 

**Example:**

    var test = null;
    
    test.push('hello world');
    
    console.log(test); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

Answer (score -2):

it's pretty much your choice, but I will go with  `undefined` rather than `null` because they are `undefined` after all and it would not confuse me during testing. But there would be no problem with `null` too.

Comment: `undefined` is the default value if you just declare `let userdetails;`